# OctoPack Nuget Error

Tags: octopus-deploy

We just started just `Octopus Deploy` and installed `OctoPack` in our `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET 4.6)`. When i enter and run this command: `/p: RunOctoPack=true`, it's all fine. However when i enter further command `/p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://blahblah`, it starts throwing me the following error:

```
C:\Builds\11\Vocal Area VA\VA Octo\src\VA\DEV 1\Telrik\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\OctoPack.targets (109): The command ""C:\Builds\11\Vocal Area VA\VA Octo\src\VA\DEV 1\Telrik\packages\OctoPack.3.6.1\build\nuget.exe" push "C:\Builds\11\Vocal Area VA\VA Octo\src\VA\DEV 1\Telrik\DSC.VA.WEB\obj\octopacked\DSC.VA.WEB.1.0.0.0.nupkg"  -Source http://octodeploy/nuget/packages " exited with code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and push the package manually via NuGet.exe command line tool.

```
nuget.exe push -Source {NuGet package source URL} -ApiKey key {your_package}.nupkg
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

/p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctoPackPackageVersion=${Your_octoPackPackageVersion} /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp={Your_Adress} /p:OctoPackPublishApiKey={Your_ApiKey}, encoding: "UTF-8"

Could you refactor your script with it ? Should work.